# declaration/definition order dependency

Tags: c++, class, gcc, forward-declaration

I have a code like this (C++):

```
namespace models
{
    class model
    {
        private:
            ui::window* win;
    };
}

namespace ui
{
    class window
    {
        private:
            models::model* modl;
    };
}
```

As you can see its such a shout-rising hell. As you well know this code doesn't compile, unless I provide a forward declaration for `window` before models, which is not rational to do so in general, since the above is not the entire code and also the code will be expanding.

Is there a systematic approach to this?

Comment: Don't create cyclic dependencies is usually the best solution.

Comment: Well it depends on what the classes do. I'll let you figure the design out.

Comment: What is wrong with the mindset of a cyclic design, in general? Shouldn't it ever show up in any design anywhere at all in the field of computer programming?

Comment: Of course there exist designs where they work, but generally they're not worth the trouble they cause. The Wikipedia page lists some problems: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> unless I provide a forward declaration for window before models, which is not rational to do so in general

Actually, it is. You should use forward declarations instead of inclusions or full definitions wherever possible.

But most important, your design looks awckward at least.

EDIT: Per request, code with forward declarations:

```
namespace ui
{
    class window;
}
namespace models
{
    class model
    {
        private:
            ui::window* win;
    };
}

//required if this is in a different file
namespace models
{
    class model;
}
namespace ui
{
    class window
    {
        private:
            models::model* modl;
    };
}
```

Comment: Then, what kind of design would you propose for this problem?

Comment: Didn't downvote but the OP states *above is not the entire code and also the code will be expanding.* Forward Declaration works only as long as the compiler need not need to know the memory layouts of the type.Given that the fully expanded code can't just do with Forward declarations.OP is asking for an *systematic approach to this hell?*

Comment: @ai64 there is no problem in your question, only some classes that depend on each other.

Comment: @Als If the code is going to expand in the same manner (i.e. pointer members), forward declarations will do. If the definitions is required, it's not possible to replace it with a forward declaration, which I already mentioned.

Comment: @ai64: Using abstract interfaces would be a good start; have the model interact with an abstract `view` interface rather than a concrete `ui::window` class.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I didn't see any of those, When I saw this answer, So it was perhaps edited later.

Comment: @Als ummm... I only added the last sentence later.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore OK, if so, how should I write this code to be compile-able in C++?

Comment: It is impossible to create circular dependencies for embedded structs/classes (both syntactically and logically), but circular *pointers*, such as these, are **absolutely normal practice**, and are completely necessary for many tree/list/graph type data structures. They are achieved exactly as in @LuchianGrigore's answer. In fact the syntax is defined this way exactly for this purpose (that and modular abstraction).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. However it seems to end up in a mess after a while, if the elements (classes here) in the project are about to grow both in definition and count, am I right?

Comment: @ai64 if they grow in definition, it shouldn't matter. If they grow in count, you'll just have to forward-declare them. However, if you run into this, it's probable that your design is not loosley coupled enough. You should post a question with your actual problem at hand and ask for suggestions on a better design.

Comment: @ams Thanks for telling me about that :) (You regulated the atmosphere :-D )

Answer (score 2):

Next would be a solution to break cyclic dependency.
The [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) would be more flexible.

```
namespace models
{
    class modelUser
    {
       virtual void handleModelUpdate() = 0;
       virtual ~modelUser
    }
    class model
    {
        public:
            model(modelUser* user) : mUser(user) { }
        private:
            modelUser* mUser;
    };
}

namespace ui
{
    class window: public models::modelUser
    {
        private:
            models::model* modl;
            virtual void handleModelUpdate() { std::cout << "update from model\n"; }
    };
}
```

Comment: But this is a totally different design. Not only you inherit from `modelUser`, which probably is wrong, but also `modelUser` no longer has a pointer to a `window`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore different design, but removing some of the flaws of the original. Assuming OP wants some kind of MVC, M shouldn't know anything about windows.

Comment: @juanchopanza removing some but adding others. I think inheriting from `modelUser` is actually worse that what he already has.

Comment: @stefaanv Thanks for this asnwer. However observer is more suitable when it comes to a fully MVCized implementation. In my current project, where total number of windows doesn't exceed 10 there's just 1 "top" window with a few "under/slave/..." windows, the borders between M, V and C are so blurry. In fact when I begun writing I told myself "There's no need for such a Controller thing! :-D ". Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: obviously, you would pass a window object to model, but the model object shouldn't care whether its user has a pointer to it or not.  I honestly don't see what is worse in this solution (unless window and model must be entangled)

Comment: It's worse in that it abuses inheritance.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I agree it is a bit heavy. The observer can be implemented with very little coupling using `std::functions` as callbacks, for example.

Comment: I agree that this shouldn't replace every cyclic dependency, but it is definitely something to consider if it would fit in the design (as in this model/view)